# 320dp wide image taking up entire screen of Android emulator

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, imageview

I have a banner which is `320dp` wide but it is filling the entire width of a `480x800` android emulator.

**Here is the XML for the banner:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/add_banner"
android:layout_width="320dip"
android:layout_height="50dip"
>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/add_image"
    android:layout_width="320dip"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:src="@drawable/your_ad_here"
    />

    <Button android:id="@+id/btn_addclose"
    android:layout_width="25dip"
    android:layout_height="25dip"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/add_image"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/add_image"
    android:text="x"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have included it in my **main.xml** file as :

```
<include android:id="@+id/add_banner" 
layout="@layout/tlp_add_banner"  
android:layout_width="320dp" 
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
```

To make sure that my emulator is `480x800`, I even logged the metrics on runtime. It is `480x800`. Then why is the banner taking up the entire width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dip` means **density-independent pixels**. Your 480x800 emulator is most probably HDPI (high density, or high dots per inch), which means that 320dp will translate to 320*1.5 actual pixels (which is 480). Only on an MDPI (medium density) screen, where the scale factor is 1 will you actually get 320 pixels.

You can get the scale factor for the current screen like this:

```
float scale = getResuorces().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```

If you really want it to be 320 **pixels** wide, regardless of the screen density (this is not recommended at all), you can just specify:

```
android:layout_width="320px"
```

Comment: I tried providing alternate resources, I put a 240dpi(high density) 320x50 image in the `drawable-hdpi` folder. Still didn't help.

Comment: Android doesn't care about the DPI set in the actual image (that's just metadata, and in many cases it could be wrong). Just put a 480x75 image in `drawable-hdpi` (I just multiplied the width and height by 1.5).

Answer (score 0):

dip aren't physical pixels but a made up number that depends on the display density. More info here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html